# I cannot get the accurate height of an element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I use the following function to get the full height of an element:

```
outerHeight1=(el)=> {
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

    return (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("height").replace("px",""))+
        parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("border-bottom-width").replace("px",""), 10)+
        parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("border-top-width").replace("px",""), 10)
    );
}
```

It is noteworthy that the elements are added dynamically to the dom.
What I see is the rendered height that I checked in chrome  is about 3 px more than what my function returns so the rendered dom returns 55 but my function returns 52.

Any idea?

Update:

as suggested I used getBoundingClientRect and I get 0 for height.
Here is the log in my console

[image]

Comment: The height of an element depends on a few things, including which box-model https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model you are using. I'm presuming you want the full outer height of the visible element which would include the height of the content, plus padding, plus borders, but not the margin... is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` it shall return an object where one of its keys is `height`.
[You can read the docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: What is the element you ran it for? What do you see in the inspector for it?

Comment: it is div. but it is hidden at the time when I call the function

Comment: Oh, that's why you get zeros for all keys. Until the element is not rendered it won't have an height, width etc.. Try and calculate the height when it renders. YOu can try and use `visibility: hidden` for the time being if you don't want to display it before whatever manipulation you are trying to apply

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `element.offsetHeight` ? It would return element's height including padding and border

Comment: console.log(el.offsetHeight); returns 0. Please see my update in the post

Comment: offsetHeight also has an issue that it will round number for example 10.5 will be returned as 11px.